# Best practice for storing a large number of a specific object in memory to be later sifted through to find a specific object?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am designing a system where I have a somewhat complex object called Item. Item looks a little like this:

```
public class Item {
    String name; //name for item
    int id;// id of the item to be used for index and lookup purposes internally
    //lots of internal methods for management, getters and setters, etc
....
```

I need to be able to, given a specific `id`, find a reference to a specific `Item`. I know that there are a large number of container data types, but I don't know which one would work best. Since I'm searching via an `int`, I didn't think that a Hash Table would be appropriate, and I know for certain that a regular-old array would lead to performance issues down the line once there are enough items involved.

Here is an example of a scenario I might end up in.

An `id` of `404` is passed to a lookup function. This function searches through a data structure to find the Item that matches `404` and returns a new instance of that item.

So I've thought that perhaps a `Map` would do? Please enlighten me as to

a) whether or not this is a good approach to looking up the specific `Item` object that an `id` refers to

and

b) which data types would be a good fit for the strategy I do choose to go with.

Comment: `HashTable` is a  `Map` implementation.

Comment: You can use `HashMap<Integer, Item>`. It will look up keys very quickly.

Comment: *"I didn't think that a Hash Table would be appropriate"* Why not? It is entirely appropriate to use a [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) *(concept)*, as long as you don't try to use [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) *(Java class)*, but instead use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: depending on how complex this gets and where you store or how you create those values to get returned. You may want to use H2,Derby or SqlLite  and let the db handle storage and lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to keep everything in memory, I believe a Hashtable is what you want to use. You could use the Java HashMap implementation of a Hashtable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: You do **not** want to use [`java.util.Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)